# How can I open any .pdf file in the document library in a web part?

Tags: web-part, pdf

I am using SharePoint 2019 on premise version. I have a large document library of PDF file. I want to open any of the file in a web part not in new browser tab. Is there any way I can accomplish this task ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can display PDF files inside the content editor web part. Here is how: add a Content Editor web part to the page and place the object tag as below in HTML Source of the content editor web part.

**Using Object Tag to display pdf document in CEWP:**

```
<object width="400" height="500" type="application/pdf"
data="http://sp10.Crescent.com//MCM/Documents/Pre-Reads.pdf?#zoom=75&scrollbar=1&toolbar=1&navpanes=1"
 id="pdf_content">
```

[image: PDF viewer in SharePoint Content Editor Webpart]

**Output:**

[image: PDF Files inside Content Editor-Output]

**How can we display any pdf file dynamically from the document library?**

We can make it dynamic this way - create a list view webpart to display the document library and below to this wp add a **script editor** web part, then a write a js code to read the query string parameter along with the pdf URL or read the selected item URL , and pass this URL dynamically to the above mentioned html **data** tag (mentioned in the answer). This way we can make it dynamic.

Reference:

[Display PDF Files in Content Editor Web Part](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/05/display-pdf-inside-content-editor-web.html)

In modern SharePoint online we can use the **Embed web part** to display the PDF.

For embed web part reference, you may refer to the below article:

[How to embed a PDF in a modern SharePoint page](https://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/how-to-embed-a-pdf-in-a-modern-sharepoint-page)

Comment: Thank you Habibur Rahman.But my situation is that I have a list of .PDF file not any specific one. I want to open any of them in the list. If you can help me out , will be thankful. Thank you again.

Comment: WC bro :-) for your question answer is updated

Comment: Hello Habibur Rahman, I am not a programmer. It's a rocket science to me. You mention to write a javascript for dynamically open a pdf. I have no clue. If you can help, I will be grateful . Thank you